# Contacts diff between iCloud and Google / Merge contacts into Google

Tags: icloud, google

I found out, that from some time my contacts started to save to iCloud and not to Google. Is there some easy way to show diff between my iCloud contacts and contacts stored in my Google account?

I would be even happy with some safe way how to merge iCloud contacts into Google.

I was able kind of show the difference in Contacts app on my Mac by selecting the contacts in Google account and then switch to iCloud account. But for merging all the missing into Google I would need to somehow invert the selection

Answer (score 1):

So apparently You can just export your iCloud contacts in Contacts.app (<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> then *Export* → *Export vCard…*) and then import this file into [Google contacts](https://www.google.com/contacts/).

Import is done from *Other* → *Import…* . This will create a lot of duplicates, which you can resolve by *Other* → *Find and Merge duplictes…* . I don't have the UI in English, so I translate name of the UI buttons from my head.